# How to assign the values to an array on button click

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a table in which there is button in last cell of each row when i click on that button the values of other cells in the same row stored in an array now i want if i click on button the values of it rows should stored in an array which is working but if i click on another button of the other row the values of its rows should store in another array not overwirte the values in first array and when i click the button 3rd time in another row it should give the message "you have selected 2 row"
I don't want that if 3rd time i click button it shouldn't store its values in any array 
and I want first and second click should store their corresponding values in different arrays

```
    $('#tbl tbody').on( 'click', 'td:last-child', function (e) {
  var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

            var datas=[];
            var data=[];
            var imgs=[];
            var img=[];
  var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (target) {
        var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");

        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length-2; i++) {
            img = cells[i].querySelector('img');
            if(img){
                data.push(img.src);
            }else{
            data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);}
        }
    }

});
```

In this when i click on the button which in last cell of each row then I get the values of the corresponding cells in same row[image: this is picture of my table u canthe button in last cell of each row]

This is code of my table

```
<table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                      <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Auth Provider</th>
                        <th scope="col">Auth Unique Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Match Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Game Mode</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 1</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 2</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 3</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 4</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 5</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 6</th>
                        <th scope="col">Match Time</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                        <th scope="col">Schedule Match</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>

            </table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var trHTML = "";

            $.ajax({
                url: '../php/admin/schedule_match.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {},
                success: function(response) {

                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                    var table;
                    //table.clear();
                     table = $('#tbl').DataTable(); 
                     table.clear();
                     if(data!='') {               
                      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                         table.row.add([ data[i].name, data[i].provider,data[i].auth,data[i].mid,data[i].mode,'<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p1 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p2 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p3 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p4 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p5 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p6 + '>',data[i].time,'<button class="btn btn-primary delete" data-id-id=' + data[i].id + '>Delete</button>','<button class="btn btn-primary schedule" data-id-id=' + data[i].id + '>Schedule</button>']);
                     });
                         table.draw();

                }
            }
        })
        });
```

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: @Addis i have uploaded code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, the data will be saved in `selected` variable key = tr index and value equal array list of tr child values,

```
$(function() {

      var selected = { };


      $('#tbl tbody').on( 'click', 'td:last-child', function (e) {
         var index =  $(this).closest("tr").index();

        if(Object.keys(selected).length == 2 ){
           alert("You can selecto two only");
           return;
         }

       if( selected.hasOwnProperty(index)){
         alert("You have already select this");
         return;
       }

        var children =  $(this).closest("tr").children();
        var childData = [];
        selected[index] = [];


         for (var i = 0; i < children.length-2; i++) {

            img = children[i].querySelector('img');
            if(img){
                childData.push(img.src);
            }else{
            childData.push(children[i].innerHTML);}
        }

        selected[index] = childData ; 

        console.log(selected);


     });



});
```

the output like this

```
{
  0: ["123", "asd", "123343", "asd"] ,
  2: ["13234", "asd", "123343", "asd"]
}
```

to get the selected values

```
  Object.values(selected) // [ ["123", "asd", "123343", "asd"] , ["13234", "asd", "123343", "asd"] ]
```

to get the selected tr indexes

```
  Object.keys(selected) // [ 0 , 2 ]
```

Code will check if the user select more than two rows it will alert , you can change it, if user select two and clicked on row selected before it will not get any alert, you can delete `&& !selected.hasOwnProperty(index)` to alert what ever this selected or not.

Comment: Don't get offline let me try this

Comment: and how can i disable a button on which i have already clicked ... i want if a user click on button then it should be disable or it will give alert message that u have already select this

Comment: How can i access the values stored in selected array separately?

Comment: Actually i want to send the values of both rows in an ajax request. Should I access each value separately ?

Comment: `Object.values(selected)` will return two arrays of selected values, you can submit it to the backend and access it by index so `Object.values(selected)[0]` =  `["123", "asd", "123343", "asd"]` and `Object.values(selected)[1]` = `["13234", "asd", "123343", "asd"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot dude salute to u ... u have solved a big problem for me

Comment: i need to ask something

Comment: Okay ask please

Comment: as u know that in last row there is a button i click the button and everything is according to plan but i want that when on last cell for first time then the text of button should be change.. I used $(this).textcontent("selected") In this case the button in cell vanishes and text of cell becomes selected i want to change the text of button to selected

Comment: You can use `$(this).find("button").text("Selected")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199193/discussion-between-yasser-mas-and---).

Comment: can u answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853021/how-to-apply-the-condition-in-javascript-that-row-has-been-filled