# How to decrease the values using a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hey there actually i made a an html page on which there are two portion when i click in first portion the number increases and when i click in second portion the number in second portion increases. I used javascript for it. Now i made a button at the bottom of each page . I want when i click on that button the number should decrease i tried a lot of methods but everytime i fail 
When u will run the snipet click on start button u will see minus button i want when i click on that score should decrease

```js
     angular.module('scoreKeeper', []).
controller('score', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.gameInfo = {
    gameStarted: false,
    servesSinceSwitch: 0,
    scoreSwitchMode: 0,
    numberOfPlayers: 2 };


  $scope.team1 = {
    name: "Team 1",
    score: 0,
    serving: false };

  $scope.team2 = {
    name: "Team 2",
    score: 0,
    serving: false };


  $scope.player1 = {
    name: "P1",
    serving: true };


  $scope.player2 = {
    name: "P2",
    serving: true };


  $scope.player3 = {
    name: null,
    serving: false };


  $scope.player4 = {
    name: null,
    serving: false };


  $scope.startGame = function () {$scope.gameInfo.gameStarted = true;};

  $scope.players = function (n) {
    $scope.gameInfo.numberOfPlayers = n;
    if (n == 2) {
      $scope.player3.name = null;
      $scope.player4.name = null;
    } else {
      $scope.player3.name = "P3";
      //$scope.player3.serving = true;
      $scope.player4.name = "P4";
    //$scope.player4.serving = true;

    }

  };
  $scope.addPoint = function (i) {
    // Start the game, give the Serving class to the person who won the rally
    if (!$scope.team1.serving && !$scope.team2.serving) {
      $scope['team' + i].serving = true;
      $scope.footer.message = "Game on!";
    } else {

      // Increment the player's score, how many serves since the last switch, and the highest current score
      $scope['team' + i].score++;
      $scope.gameInfo.servesSinceSwitch++;
      $scope.gameInfo.highestScore = Math.max($scope.team1.score, $scope.team2.score);

      // Echo who's in the lead or if it's tied
      if ($scope.team1.score > $scope.team2.score) {
        if ($scope.player3.name) {
          $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore = $scope.team1.name;
        } else {
          $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore = $scope.player1.name;
        }
        $scope.footer.message = $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore + " is in the lead";
      } else if ($scope.team1.score < $scope.team2.score) {
        if ($scope.player3.name) {
          $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore = $scope.team2.name;
        } else {
          $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore = $scope.player2.name;
        }
        $scope.footer.message = $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore + " is in the lead";
      } else if ($scope.team1.score == $scope.team2.score) {
        $scope.footer.message = "Game is tied";
      }

      if ($scope.team1.score == 10 && $scope.team2.score == 10) {
        $scope.gameInfo.scoreSwitchMode = 1;
      }

      // Figure out if serves are switching by 5
      if ($scope.gameInfo.servesSinceSwitch == 5 && $scope.gameInfo.scoreSwitchMode == 0) {
        $(".team").toggleClass("team__isServing");
        $scope.team1.serving = !$scope.team1.serving;
        $scope.team2.serving = !$scope.team2.serving;

        if ($scope.gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4) {
          if ($scope.team1.serving) {
            $scope.player1.serving = !$scope.player1.serving;
            $scope.player3.serving = !$scope.player3.serving;
          } else {
            $scope.player2.serving = !$scope.player2.serving;
            $scope.player4.serving = !$scope.player4.serving;
          }
        }
        $scope.gameInfo.servesSinceSwitch = 0;

        // Or by 1
      } else if ($scope.gameInfo.scoreSwitchMode == 1) {
        $(".team").toggleClass("team__isServing");
        $scope.team1.serving = !$scope.team1.serving;
        $scope.team2.serving = !$scope.team2.serving;
        if ($scope.gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4) {
          if ($scope.team1.serving) {
            $scope.player1.serving = !$scope.player1.serving;
            $scope.player3.serving = !$scope.player3.serving;
          } else {
            $scope.player2.serving = !$scope.player2.serving;
            $scope.player4.serving = !$scope.player4.serving;
          }
        }
      }

      // Figure out if the game is over and who won
      if (Math.abs($scope.team1.score - $scope.team2.score) >= 2 && $scope.gameInfo.highestScore >= 21) {
        $(".scoreBoard").addClass("dimmed");
        $scope.footer.message = "Game over! " + $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore + " wins!";
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.footer = {
    message: "Rally for serve" };

}]);
```

```css
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #ECF0C9;
}

.score {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #ECF0C9;
  font-size: 20vmax;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.score > span {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scoreBoard {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.team {
  color: #ECF0C9;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.team.team-1 {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.team.team-1 .player-right {
  background: #45B29D;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.team.team-1 .player-left {
  background: #DF5A49;
}
.team.team-1 .serving__isServing {
  order: 1;
}
.team.team-1 .serving__isNotServing {
  order: -1;
}
.team.team-2 {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
.team.team-2 .player-left {
  background: #E27A3F;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.team.team-2 .player-right {
  background: #EFC94C;
}
.team.team-2 .serving__isServing {
  order: -1;
}
.team.team-2 .serving__isNotServing {
  order: 1;
}
.team.team__isServing .serving__isServing {
  color: #ECF0C9;
  animation: serving 1s infinite reverse;
}

.player {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.player input {
  width: 90%;
  height: 10vh;
  background: #334D5C;
  color: #ECF0C9;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8vh;
}
.player.player-alone {
  order: 3;
}

header, input.teamName {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #334D5C;
  color: #6b7e7d;
  max-height: 10vh;
  font-size: 8vh;
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes serving {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  font-size: 5vmin;
  color: #334D5C;
}
footer.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 2vw;
}
footer.menu div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
footer.menu button {
  background: #334D5C;
  color: #ECF0C9;
  border: none;
  height: 9vh;
  font-size: 7vh;
  padding: 0 2vw;
}
footer.menu button.notSelected {
  color: #909f93;
}

.dimmed {
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="scoreKeeper" ng-controller="score">
  
  <div class="screen screen-start" ng-if="!gameInfo.gameStarted">
    <div class="scoreBoard">
      
      <div class="team team-1">
        <input type="text" class="teamName" ng-model="team1.name" ng-if="gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4"></input>
        <div class="player player-left">
          <input type="text" ng-model="player1.name"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="player player-right player-serveSpot" ng-if="gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4">
          <input type="text" ng-model="player3.name"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="team team-2">
        <input type="text" class="teamName" ng-model="team2.name" ng-if="gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4"></input>
        <div class="player player-right">
          <input type="text" ng-model="player2.name"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="player player-left" ng-if="gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4">
          <input type="text" ng-model="player4.name"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <footer class="menu">
      <div>
        <button ng-click="players(2)" ng-class="{'notSelected':gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4}">2</button>
        <button ng-click="players(4)" ng-class="{'notSelected':gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 2}">4</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button ng-click="startGame()">START</button>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  
  <div class="score" ng-if="team1.serving || team2.serving">
    <span>{{team1.score}}</span>
    <span>{{team2.score}}</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="screen screen-game" ng-if="gameInfo.gameStarted">
    <div class="scoreBoard">
      
      <div class="team team-1" ng-click="addPoint(1)" ng-class="{'team__isServing':team1.serving}">
        <header ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player1.serving, 'serving__isNotServing':!player1.serving}">{{player1.name}}</header>
        <div class="player player-left" ng-class="{'player-alone':!player3.name}" style="position:relative">       
            <h3  type="button"  id="subt1" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 10px;font-size: 50px;color: white;font-weight:bolder;    margin: 0px !important;cursor: pointer;">-</h3></div>
        <div class="player player-right player-serveSpot" ng-if="player3.name"></div>
        <header ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player3.serving, 'serving__isNotServing':!player3.serving}" ng-if="player3.name">{{player3.name}}</header>
             </div>
      
      <div class="team team-2" ng-click="addPoint(2)" ng-class="{'team__isServing':team2.serving}">
        <header ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player2.serving, 'serving__isNotServing':!player2.serving}">{{player2.name}}</header>
        <div class="player player-right" ng-class="{'player-alone':!player3.name}"style="position:relative">   
            <h1  type="button"  id="subt2"style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 10px;font-size: 50px;color: white;font-weight:bolder;    margin: 0px !important;cursor: pointer;">-</h1></div>
        <div class="player player-left" ng-if="player4.name"></div>
        <header ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player4.serving, 'serving__isNotServing':!player4.serving}" ng-if="player4.name">{{player4.name}}</header>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <footer>{{footer.message}}</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you need an event listener for either the button or the subt1/2 id and decrement the score that way.

Comment: Can u change the code?

Comment: remove h3 from inside the div with addPoint.

Comment: Hey can u answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969218/handling-a-event-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button has no functionality attached to it.. 
The problem is here:

```
<div class="team team-1" ng-click="addPoint(1)" ....>
 <h3  type="button"  id="subt1" style="...">-</h3></div>    
</div>

ng-click="addPoint(-1)"
```

you'll have something like

```
 <h3  type="button" ng-click="addPoint(-1)"  id="subt1" style="...">-</h3></div>
```

you need to add `negative` one when they click the button.

also  change `<h3 type="button"` to just `<button></button>`
or `<input type="submit">`

Update: 
The problem is here!

```
<div class="team team-1" ng-click="addPoint(1)" ....>
 <h3  type="button"  id="subt1" style="...">-</h3></div>    
</div>
```

you have the `h3` nested inside the addPoints element. 
you can not click on the h3 element without clicking on the addPoint element.

because the h3 is a child of the addPoints.
You NEED to remove it 
you can still position it in the same place but when its not nested.

```
 <h3  type="button" ng-click="addPoint(-1)"  id="subt1" style="...">-</h3>
```

then add the appropriate javascript logic. 
i would change addPoint() to addPoint(element_number, points_to_add)
so you do addPoint(1, -1)

actually i would change all the code.

Comment: there is a change in javascript is required also

Comment: yes. the solution is to put a function on the button. change javascript accordingly

Comment: i tried a lot of ways i tried recently this one `$scope.delPoint = function (i) {
   
      $scope['team' + i].score-=1;
      $scope.gameInfo.servesSinceSwitch-=1;
      $scope.gameInfo.highestScore = Math.max($scope.team1.score, $scope.team2.score);
}` but it decreases only 1 time

Comment: your problem is that the button is nested inside the element calling the function.. see my answer. 
That wont work. 
  $scope.addPoint = function (i, number_of_points_to_add) { //where i is the team number

you need to change to this ng-click="addPoint(2,1)
then instead of $scope['team' + i].score++;
you do
$scope['team' + i].score += number_of_points_to_add;

then remove the h1 from being nested in the add points div.

Comment: with your solution of $scope.delPoint = function (i);
everytime you click it will addPoint, then it will delPoint. so you wont see anychange. 
you are running two funcitons because one function is nested in another. the elements are nested

Comment: Hey can u answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969218/handling-a-event-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 .metric{width: 300px; height: 100px; border: 5px solid red; margin:20px;
  font-size: 24px;}
</style>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <div class="container">
  <div class="metric" ng-click="addPoint(player_one, 1)">
   P1 Click To Add Point<br>
   {{player_one.score}}
  </div>
  <div class="metric" ng-click="addPoint(player_two, 1)">
   P2 Click To Add Point<br>
   {{player_two.score}}
  </div>
  <div class="metric" ng-click="addPoint(player_one, -1)">
   P1 Click To Remove Point<br>
   {{player_one.score}}
  </div>
  <div class="metric" ng-click="addPoint(player_two, -1)">
   P2 Click To Remove Point<br>
   {{player_two.score}}
  </div>
 </div>




</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.player_one = {score:0};
  $scope.player_two = {score:0};

  $scope.addPoint = function(player, points_to_add){
   if(player.score >= 0 ) {
    player.score += points_to_add;
    }
    if(player.score == -1) {
     player.score = 0;
    }
  }



});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey can u answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969218/handling-a-event-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it by doing this.

in HTML

```
 <header  ng-click="addPoint(1, 1)" ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player1.serving, 
 <h3   ng-click="addPoint(2, -1)"    type="button"  id="subt1"
```

in JS

```
 $scope.addPoint = function (i, points_to_add)
```

so now you will have to click on the header to add...
[image]
see code below. (run the snippet)

```js
angular.module('scoreKeeper', []).
controller('score', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.gameInfo = {
    gameStarted: false,
    servesSinceSwitch: 0,
    scoreSwitchMode: 0,
    numberOfPlayers: 2 };


  $scope.team1 = {
    name: "Team 1",
    score: 0,
    serving: false };

  $scope.team2 = {
    name: "Team 2",
    score: 0,
    serving: false };


  $scope.player1 = {
    name: "P1",
    serving: true };


  $scope.player2 = {
    name: "P2",
    serving: true };


  $scope.player3 = {
    name: null,
    serving: false };


  $scope.player4 = {
    name: null,
    serving: false };


  $scope.startGame = function () {$scope.gameInfo.gameStarted = true;};

  $scope.players = function (n) {
    $scope.gameInfo.numberOfPlayers = n;
    if (n == 2) {
      $scope.player3.name = null;
      $scope.player4.name = null;
    } else {
      $scope.player3.name = "P3";
      //$scope.player3.serving = true;
      $scope.player4.name = "P4";
    //$scope.player4.serving = true;

    }

  };
  $scope.addPoint = function (i, points_to_add) {
    // Start the game, give the Serving class to the person who won the rally
    if (!$scope.team1.serving && !$scope.team2.serving) {
      $scope['team' + i].serving = true;
      $scope.footer.message = "Game on!";
    } else {

      // Increment the player's score, how many serves since the last switch, and the highest current score
      $scope['team' + i].score+=points_to_add;

      if ($scope['team' + i].score== -1) {
       $scope['team' + i].score=0;

      }



      $scope.gameInfo.servesSinceSwitch++;
      $scope.gameInfo.highestScore = Math.max($scope.team1.score, $scope.team2.score);

      // Echo who's in the lead or if it's tied
      if ($scope.team1.score > $scope.team2.score) {
        if ($scope.player3.name) {
          $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore = $scope.team1.name;
        } else {
          $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore = $scope.player1.name;
        }
        $scope.footer.message = $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore + " is in the lead";
      } else if ($scope.team1.score < $scope.team2.score) {
        if ($scope.player3.name) {
          $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore = $scope.team2.name;
        } else {
          $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore = $scope.player2.name;
        }
        $scope.footer.message = $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore + " is in the lead";
      } else if ($scope.team1.score == $scope.team2.score) {
        $scope.footer.message = "Game is tied";
      }

      if ($scope.team1.score == 10 && $scope.team2.score == 10) {
        $scope.gameInfo.scoreSwitchMode = 1;
      }

      // Figure out if serves are switching by 5
      if ($scope.gameInfo.servesSinceSwitch == 5 && $scope.gameInfo.scoreSwitchMode == 0) {
        $(".team").toggleClass("team__isServing");
        $scope.team1.serving = !$scope.team1.serving;
        $scope.team2.serving = !$scope.team2.serving;

        if ($scope.gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4) {
          if ($scope.team1.serving) {
            $scope.player1.serving = !$scope.player1.serving;
            $scope.player3.serving = !$scope.player3.serving;
          } else {
            $scope.player2.serving = !$scope.player2.serving;
            $scope.player4.serving = !$scope.player4.serving;
          }
        }
        $scope.gameInfo.servesSinceSwitch = 0;

        // Or by 1
      } else if ($scope.gameInfo.scoreSwitchMode == 1) {
        $(".team").toggleClass("team__isServing");
        $scope.team1.serving = !$scope.team1.serving;
        $scope.team2.serving = !$scope.team2.serving;
        if ($scope.gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4) {
          if ($scope.team1.serving) {
            $scope.player1.serving = !$scope.player1.serving;
            $scope.player3.serving = !$scope.player3.serving;
          } else {
            $scope.player2.serving = !$scope.player2.serving;
            $scope.player4.serving = !$scope.player4.serving;
          }
        }
      }

      // Figure out if the game is over and who won
      if (Math.abs($scope.team1.score - $scope.team2.score) >= 2 && $scope.gameInfo.highestScore >= 21) {
        $(".scoreBoard").addClass("dimmed");
        $scope.footer.message = "Game over! " + $scope.gameInfo.teamWithHighScore + " wins!";
      }
    }
  };

  $scope.footer = {message: "Rally for serve" };

}]);
```

```css
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #ECF0C9;
}

.score {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #ECF0C9;
  font-size: 20vmax;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.score > span {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.screen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scoreBoard {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.team {
  color: #ECF0C9;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.team.team-1 {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.team.team-1 .player-right {
  background: #45B29D;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.team.team-1 .player-left {
  background: #DF5A49;
}
.team.team-1 .serving__isServing {
  order: 1;
}
.team.team-1 .serving__isNotServing {
  order: -1;
}
.team.team-2 {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
.team.team-2 .player-left {
  background: #E27A3F;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.team.team-2 .player-right {
  background: #EFC94C;
}
.team.team-2 .serving__isServing {
  order: -1;
}
.team.team-2 .serving__isNotServing {
  order: 1;
}
.team.team__isServing .serving__isServing {
  color: #ECF0C9;
  animation: serving 1s infinite reverse;
}

.player {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.player input {
  width: 90%;
  height: 10vh;
  background: #334D5C;
  color: #ECF0C9;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8vh;
}
.player.player-alone {
  order: 3;
}

header, input.teamName {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #334D5C;
  color: #6b7e7d;
  max-height: 10vh;
  font-size: 8vh;
  flex: 1;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes serving {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  font-size: 5vmin;
  color: #334D5C;
}
footer.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 2vw;
}
footer.menu div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
footer.menu button {
  background: #334D5C;
  color: #ECF0C9;
  border: none;
  height: 9vh;
  font-size: 7vh;
  padding: 0 2vw;
}
footer.menu button.notSelected {
  color: #909f93;
}

.dimmed {
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
 
<body ng-app="scoreKeeper" ng-controller="score">
  
  <div class="screen screen-start" ng-if="!gameInfo.gameStarted">
    <div class="scoreBoard">
      
      <div class="team team-1">
        <input type="text" class="teamName" ng-model="team1.name" ng-if="gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4"></input>
        <div class="player player-left">
          <input type="text" ng-model="player1.name"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="player player-right player-serveSpot" ng-if="gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4">
          <input type="text" ng-model="player3.name"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="team team-2">
        <input type="text" class="teamName" ng-model="team2.name" ng-if="gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4"></input>
        <div class="player player-right">
          <input type="text" ng-model="player2.name"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="player player-left" ng-if="gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4">
          <input type="text" ng-model="player4.name"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <footer class="menu">
      <div>
        <button ng-click="players(2)" ng-class="{'notSelected':gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 4}">2</button>
        <button ng-click="players(4)" ng-class="{'notSelected':gameInfo.numberOfPlayers == 2}">4</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button ng-click="startGame()">START</button>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
  
  <div class="score" ng-if="team1.serving || team2.serving">
    <span>{{team1.score}}</span>
    <span>{{team2.score}}</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="screen screen-game" ng-if="gameInfo.gameStarted">
    <div class="scoreBoard">
      
      <div class="team team-1" ng-class="{'team__isServing':team1.serving}">
        <header  ng-click="addPoint(1, 1)"  ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player1.serving, 'serving__isNotServing':!player1.serving}">{{player1.name}}</header>
        <div class="player player-left" ng-class="{'player-alone':!player3.name}" style="position:relative">       
            <h3   ng-click="addPoint(2, -1)"    type="button"  id="subt1" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 10px;font-size: 50px;color: white;font-weight:bolder;    margin: 0px !important;cursor: pointer;">-</h3></div>
        <div class="player player-right player-serveSpot" ng-if="player3.name"></div>
        <header ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player3.serving, 'serving__isNotServing':!player3.serving}" ng-if="player3.name">{{player3.name}}</header>
             </div>
      
      <div class="team team-2" ng-class="{'team__isServing':team2.serving}">
        <header  ng-click="addPoint(2, 1)"  ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player2.serving, 'serving__isNotServing':!player2.serving}">{{player2.name}}</header>
        <div class="player player-right" ng-class="{'player-alone':!player3.name}"style="position:relative">   
            <h1  ng-click="addPoint(2, -1)"   type="button"  id="subt2"style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 10px;font-size: 50px;color: white;font-weight:bolder;    margin: 0px !important;cursor: pointer;">-</h1></div>
        <div class="player player-left" ng-if="player4.name"></div>
        <header ng-class="{'serving__isServing':player4.serving, 'serving__isNotServing':!player4.serving}" ng-if="player4.name">{{player4.name}}</header>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <footer>{{footer.message}}</footer>
  </div>


 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey can u answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969218/handling-a-event-in-angular-js