# Decrement the function value continously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey there actually i made a html page on which there are two portion when i click in first portion the number increases and when i click in second portion the number in second portion increases. I used Angular JS for it. Now i made a button at the bottom of each page . I want when i click on that button the number should decrease but i used the function when i click on button it decreases only one time. If u have further queries [How to decrease the values using a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912891/how-to-decrease-the-values-using-a-function/57915516#57915516) 
I have a further detail here

```
<button  type="button" ng-click="delPoint(1)"  id="sub1"
         style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 10px;font-size: 50px;color: white;font-weight:bolder;    margin: 0px !important;cursor: pointer;">-</button>

<button  type="button" ng-click="delPoint(2)" id="sub2"
         style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 10px;font-size: 50px;color: white;font-weight:bolder;    margin: 0px !important;cursor: pointer;">-</button>
```

```
$scope.delPoint = function (j) {
   if ($scope.team1.score > 0 && $scope.team2.score >0){
      $scope['team' + j].score--;
      $scope.gameInfo.servesSinceSwitch--;
   }
```

Comment: Could it just be a logic error? You only decrease the value if both teams score is 1 or  more. For example if the current score for team one is 7 and team two is 0 then your code wont allow you to decrease either team.

Comment: see answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912891/how-to-decrease-the-values-using-a-function/57930975#57930975

Comment: Hey can u answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969218/handling-a-event-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Game</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 .app{
  width: 1040px;
  /*border: 5px solid red;*/
  height: 800px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: #ECF0C9;
 }
 .player{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 470px;
    height: 621px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
 }
 .centered{
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*border: 5px solid red;*/
    font-size: 140px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 457px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
 }
 .player_name{
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 37px;
  position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    background: #334D5C;
    color: #ECF0C9;
 }
 .controls{
  /*border: 5px solid red;*/
    margin: 20px;
    height: 100px;
  clear: both;
 }
 .number_of_players_option{
    /*border: 5px solid blue;*/
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;  
    float: left;
 }
 .start_game_option{
    /*border: 5px solid blue;*/
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 640px;
    float: left; 
 }
 .status_bar{
    /*border: 5px solid blue;*/
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
  width: 940px;
 }
 .reducer{
  position: absolute;
    bottom: -18px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 100px; 
  color: white;
 }
 .one{
  background: #DF5A49;  
 }
 .two{
  background: #EFC94C;  
 }
 .button{
  background: #334D5C;
    color: #ECF0C9;
    float: right;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    letter-spacing: 2px; 
 }

 .short_button{
  background: #334D5C;
    color: #ECF0C9;
    float: right;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
.name{
    text-align: center;
    background: #334D5C;
    color: #6b7e7d;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body ng-app="scoreKeeper" ng-controller="score" >

<div class="app">
 <div ng-show="show_setup" class="setup">
  <div ng-repeat="player in players" class={{player.class}}>
   <div class="centered">
    <input class="player_name" ng-model=player.name>
   </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="controls">
   <div class="number_of_players_option">
    <button class="short_button" ng-click="startGame(2)">2</button>
    
   </div>
   <div class="number_of_players_option">
    <button class="short_button" ng-click="startGame(4)">4</button>
    
   </div>
   <div ng-click="show_setup = false" class="start_game_option">
    <button class="button" ng-click="startGame()">START</button>
   </div>
  </div>  
 </div>


 <div  ng-show="!show_setup"class="game">
  <div ng-repeat="player in players" class={{player.class}}>
   <div class="name"><br>{{player.name}}</div>
   <div class="centered" ng-click="addPoint(player)">
    <h3>{{player.score}}</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="reducer" ng-click="removePoint(player)"> - </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="controls">
   <div class="status_bar">{{game_info.message}}</div>
  </div>  
 </div>





</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('scoreKeeper', []).
controller('score', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

//setup

 $scope.players = [
 {
  name:"P1", 
  score:0,
  class:"player one"
 },
  {
   name:"P2", 
   score:0,
   class:"player two"

  }
 ];

 $scope.show_setup = true;

$scope.addPoint=function(player){
 player.score++;
    if(player.score == -1){player.score=0};
}

$scope.removePoint=function(player){
 player.score--;
    if(player.score == -1){player.score=0};
}


}]); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey can u answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57969218/handling-a-event-in-angular-js

Comment: I need your help in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033537/how-to-show-data-in-a-chart