# How to show data in a chart?

Tags: javascript

Hey there actually I am retrieving some data from database
The data is is like this format

```
id: "5"
p_amount: "120"
p_date: "09/20/2019"
p_id: "12345"
p_method: "Bank"
p_status: "OPEN"
```

This is what i did in ajax response, I convert the month of date in its name

```
           success: function(response){
                    var obj=JSON.parse(response);
                     if(obj!=""){
                      $.each(obj, function(i, item) {
                         var selectedMonthName = months[obj[i].p_date.slice(0,2)-1];

                      });
                     }
```

Now i have another file of name ***main.js*** and i made a chart in javascript

```
(function ($) {
 // USE STRICT
 "use strict";


try {
   //WidgetChart 1
   var ctx = document.getElementById("widgetChart1");
   if (ctx) {
     ctx.height = 115;
     var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
       type: 'line',
       data: {
         labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August','September','October','November','December'],
         type: 'line',
         datasets: [{
           data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0], //Here data should be added e.g, if month is september the value p_amount should add here in 8th index
           label: 'Dataset',
           backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.1)',
           borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.55)',
         },]
       },
       options: {
         maintainAspectRatio: true,
         legend: {
           display: false
         },
         layout: {
           padding: {
             left: 0,
             right: 0,
             top: 0,
             bottom: 0
           }
         },
         responsive: true,
         scales: {
           xAxes: [{
             gridLines: {
               color: 'transparent',
               zeroLineColor: 'transparent'
             },
             ticks: {
               fontSize: 2,
               fontColor: 'transparent'
             }
           }],
           yAxes: [{
             display: false,
             ticks: {
               display: false,
             }
           }]
         },
         title: {
           display: false,
         },
         elements: {
           line: {
             borderWidth: 0
           },
           point: {
             radius: 0,
             hitRadius: 10,
             hoverRadius: 4
           }
         }
       }
     });
   }

 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
})(jQuery);
```

Now i want when i get the month name the data(which is retrieved from DB) in other js file should be updated

Comment: Any reason or problem moving Ajax request to main.js?

Comment: Or what about an JSON index? { "January" : 0, "February" : 1, etc. } then you can directly convert string name to predefined number. Is it answer to your question? Not sure what or where is the problem.

Comment: Ok i will move ajax to main.js

Comment: Tom can u come to teamviewer

Comment: No i want the array 'data' in main.js should replaced by json data....

Comment: yes i got your email i send a reply to you plzzz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used something like this, made chart.js object global, set its data from Ajax response and called update method.

```js
var labels = [];
var data = [];
var smallDB = {};
var lastYear = 0;
var limit = 5; // limit history to (5) years
var obj = TestData();
for (var i in obj) {
    var d = new Date(obj[i].b_date);
    var idy = d.getFullYear();
    lastYear = Math.max(lastYear, idy)
    var num = parseInt(obj[i].b_amount);
    smallDB[idy] = (smallDB[idy] || 0) + num;
}
lastYear++;
for(var i=0;i<limit;i++) {
    labels[i] = i+lastYear-limit;
    data[i] = smallDB[i+lastYear-limit] || 0;
    console.log(labels[i], data[i]);
}

function TestData() {
  return [{
    b_date:"11/01/2017",
    b_amount:"110"
},{
    b_date:"10/01/2016",
    b_amount:"100"
},{
    b_date:"01/01/2020",
    b_amount:"200"
},{
    b_date:"12/01/2018",
    b_amount:"120"
}];
};
```

This one limits last 5 years.