# Manage the timer made in a dynamic element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I am retrieving some data from database through AJAX and on retrieval of data i made some dynamic element in HTML using JavaScript. I made dynamic row in a container and in that row i making a dynamic div whose class is "col-md-4" which is child of parent row it means there can be at least 3 dynamic divs of class="col-md-4" in a dynamic row. For this purpose is used a loop in the obj.success function of AJAX. The purpose of using loop to make 3 dynamic elements in dynamic row. If don't use loop then the new row will only have one div of class col-md-4.

Now the problem I am retrieving some time from database and then taking current time I am getting the difference of both tme and then use a function to run the time. All this is loop. Now problem is timer is running only for last element in row.
I use the timer in another scenario, but for that there is no problem because there is no loop used in that scenario.

```js
var ajax = prompt('Confirm demo or paste AJAX data', '[ {"id":1}, {"id":2}, {"id":3}, {"id":4}, {"id":5}]');
display(ajax);
function display(response) {
    var n=1;
    var times = ["2019-09-19 12:59","2019-09-27 12:59","2019-12-19 12:59","2019-11-19 12:59","2019-10-19 12:59"];
    var time=new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
           var res = time.slice(0,-3);
    var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); 
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        var current=today+" "+res;
      //  alert(current);
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    if(data.length) {
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var parent= document.getElementsByClassName('carousel')[0];
            var row1= document.createElement("div");
            row1.setAttribute("class", "row");
            row1.setAttribute("id", "row"+n);
            parent.appendChild(row1);
            var crow1;
            for(var j=0;j<3 && i+j < data.length;j++) {
              crow1 = document.createElement("div");
              crow1.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4");
              crow1.setAttribute("id", data[i+j].id);
              crow1.innerText = "data" + (i+j)+" ";
              row1.appendChild(crow1);
              var distance = (new Date(times[0])).getTime() - (new Date(current)).getTime();
              var lmn = Math.floor(Math.random() *999999999999);
               var timer = document.createElement("h");
                            timer.setAttribute("id",lmn);
                            crow1.appendChild(timer);
                        var x = setInterval(function() {
                        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                        
                        document.getElementById(lmn).innerHTML =days + "days " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "mins " + seconds + "secs ";
                            distance -= 1000;
                     if (distance < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    document.getElementById(lmn).innerHTML = "¡El tiempo de partida ha comenzado!";

                }
            }, 1000);
            }
            i += 3-1;
            n++;
        }

    }
}
```

```css
DIV.col-md-4 {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #FF0080;
  margin: 5px;
}
.row {
  display: block;
  background-color: #80E080;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
</div>
```

Why is only the last element showing timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is a classic async function in a synchronous workflow issue. Inside your **setInterval**'s callback, you are using the value **lmn**. By the time this variable is accessed by the callback function,  the code flow would have cycled through the loops and **lmn** will be left with the max loop index value.

So to tackle this you enclose your async function in a closure function call and send the variable (that is set outside the async method) that is being used in that call back as a parameter to that closure call. Check the code sample below, I have updated it with a closure call.

To understand how this works better, place a checkpoint in your debug console at the point where you are using **lmn** variable in the async callback, with and without the closure call.

To know more about closures : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

```js
var ajax = prompt('Confirm demo or paste AJAX data', '[ {"id":1}, {"id":2}, {"id":3}, {"id":4}, {"id":5}]');
display(ajax);

function display(response) {
var n = 1;
var times = ["2019-09-19 12:59", "2019-09-27 12:59", "2019-12-19 12:59", "2019-11-19 12:59", "2019-10-19 12:59"];
var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
var res = time.slice(0, -3);
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
var current = today + " " + res;
//  alert(current);
var data = JSON.parse(response);
if (data.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel')[0];
        var row1 = document.createElement("div");
        row1.setAttribute("class", "row");
        row1.setAttribute("id", "row" + n);
        parent.appendChild(row1);
        var crow1;
        for (var j = 0; j < 3 && i + j < data.length; j++) {
            crow1 = document.createElement("div");
            crow1.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4");
            crow1.setAttribute("id", data[i + j].id);
            crow1.innerText = "data" + (i + j) + " ";
            row1.appendChild(crow1);
            var distance = (new Date(times[0])).getTime() - (new Date(current)).getTime();
            var lmn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999999);
            var timer = document.createElement("h");
            timer.setAttribute("id", lmn);
            crow1.appendChild(timer);
            (function(l, d){
              var x = setInterval(function() {
                  var days = Math.floor(d / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                  var hours = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                  var minutes = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                  var seconds = Math.floor((d % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                  document.getElementById(l).innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "mins " + seconds + "secs ";
                  d -= 1000;
                  if (d < 0) {
                      clearInterval(x);
                      document.getElementById(l).innerHTML = "¡El tiempo de partida ha comenzado!";

                  }
              }, 1000);

            })(lmn, distance); // This is called a closure function, use this when you are using async methods in synchronous code blocks
        }
        i += 3 - 1;
        n++;
    }

}
}
```

```css
DIV.col-md-4 {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #FF0080;
  margin: 5px;
}
.row {
  display: block;
  background-color: #80E080;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
</div>
```

Comment: there is still a problem

Comment: i told that i m retrieving values from database but only value of timer is only last one

Comment: I am not able to understand it @مہرعمرغفار, can you elaborate?

Comment: i mean to say the data coming from database is in array in every index of array the value of time is different but the code is only picking the time of last index and showing the timer same for all elements

Comment: `var distance = (new Date(data[i+j].time)).getTime() - (new Date(current)).getTime();`  I used this line here `data[i+j].time` is everytime picking the value of last index

Comment: Ok I understand your issue, I just updated one variable in your callback. I didn't see that the distance variable too was in the synchronous flow. Wait I will update the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Just add all the variables that are being set outside the asynchronous function as a parameter to the closure call. This will prevent the last array loop values from being assigned. Do check if the desired output is achieved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199648/discussion-between-survesh-jones-and---).

Comment: I need your help in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033537/how-to-show-data-in-a-chart